# Can't show list of parsed JSON into TableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I'm new to swift and don't know why `UITableView` is not showing dynamic data from `JSON` array. 
I want to get the top app list from ITunes by using `swiftyJSON` and then create a dynamic table according to parsed data. 
my problem is when I run this code all I get with the below code  is 5 row with same value in them like the picture below

how can I make it dynamic and where I'm mistaking ?
Thanks in advance.

Updated Code :

```
import UIKit



struct Apps {
    var name : String!
}

class createTable: UITableViewController {

     var tableData = [Apps]()

    //Mark Properties
    @IBOutlet var appTableView : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //Get the #1 app name from iTunes and SwiftyJSON
        DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess { (iTunesData) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data: iTunesData)


            if let appArray = json["feed"]["entry"].array {
                for appDict in appArray {
                    let appName : String! = appDict["im:name"]["label"].string
                     let ap = Apps(name: appName)
                    self.tableData.append(ap)

                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


           override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.tableData.count
            }


           override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

                //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

                    let rowData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
                    cell.textLabel!.text = rowData.name


            return cell
        }


}
```

output :

[image]

Comment: did you set the datasource and delegate? and why are you calling `DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess` within table cell row delegate method? Try calling it outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not request the data inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Request the data for example in `viewDidLoad` and *trigger* a `reload` of the tableview.

Create a custom class holding the needed data, create an array of those custom classes, use one element of that custom class for each cell.

What is

```
var appName : String!
if let appArray = json["feed"]["entry"].array {
    for appDict in appArray {
         appName = appDict["im:name"]["label"].string
    }
}
cell.textLabel!.text = appName
```

supposed to do? You run that code for *every* cell. You always assign the `appName` multiple times. `appName` will always end up to be the last name found. Therefore all labels will get the same text set.

Solution summarized.

- create a class `App` which contains a property `name` (later more)
- request the data from the AppStore in your `viewDidLoad`
- parse the retrieved data, create instances of `App`, each getting their name set, store those instances in an array `var apps = [App]()`
- trigger a reload of the tableView
- in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the `App` corresponding to the cell index
- `return apps.count` inside your `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: thanks for your good solution, but can i create a class alongside my current class which is createTable : UITableViewController ? and use it in my current class ?

Comment: @anonymox  since this is swift, it does not really matter where you create the new class, can be the same file, can be a different file. Does not matter.

Comment: so you say to remove foreach loop and send the retrieved data to the tableview to show it ?

Comment: is it possible for you to chat ?

Comment: @anonymox you don't *send* anything. You store the retrieved data in your array. And then you call something like `tableView.reloadData()`. Nope, no chat.

Comment: @anonymox looks good - the only thing missing is the call to `self.tableView.reloadData()` which should be ***right after*** the for-loop,

Comment: I did put self.tableview.reloadData()  after four loop. but are you sure it's ok because i'm getting error

Comment: I updated above post and i uploaded screen shots of error messages

Comment: @anonymox okay, change your "class" to be a "struct", or create the appropriate initializer in the class. Then remove the `: NSDictionary` explicit type. Then don't access by subscript, but simply via `rowData.name`.

Comment: I updated the above code again there  is not syntax error thanks to you but the output is empty as you can see above.

Comment: @anonymox because the reloadData is still at the wrong place. make it the first statement after the for-loop. Or the last statement in the completion block of the request

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 I really appreciate it. solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Reload should be called inside closure. `DataManager` get apps list asynchronously and after data is parsed refresh is not called

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //Get the #1 app name from iTunes and SwiftyJSON
    DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess { (iTunesData) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: iTunesData)

        if let appArray = json["feed"]["entry"].array {
            for appDict in appArray {
                let appName : String! = appDict["im:name"]["label"].string
                let ap = Apps(name: appName)
                self.tableData.append(ap)

            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the Result code for those who wants to use it.

Code :

```
//
//  createTable.swift
//  TopApps


import UIKit



struct Apps {
    var name : String!
}

class createTable: UITableViewController {

     var tableData = [Apps]()

    //Mark Properties
    @IBOutlet var appTableView : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //Get the #1 app name from iTunes and SwiftyJSON
        DataManager.getTopAppsDataFromItunesWithSuccess { (iTunesData) -> Void in
            let json = JSON(data: iTunesData)


            if let appArray = json["feed"]["entry"].array {
                for appDict in appArray {
                    let appName : String! = appDict["im:name"]["label"].string
                     let ap = Apps(name: appName)
                    self.tableData.append(ap)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


           override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.tableData.count
            }


           override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

                //Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

                    let rowData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
                    cell.textLabel!.text = rowData.name


            return cell
        }


}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Reload table view after 'for ... In' loop, in your current implementation you reload table view on every loop cycle. See my answer above :)

Comment: @DeVladinci I tried your method but it wasn't working and the empty table view was appearing on the screen